# How to cancel a drag in a Mac application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have an application that has a canvas (NSView) where a user can drag an element around. When the mouse leaves the edge of that view it becomes a drag operation.

What I would like to do is when the mouse entered the originating view again it would cancel the operation and would automatically start the move within the canvas again.

I can figure out the second part I just need to figure out how to force a drag and drop to cancel. I need to do this somehow from draggingEntered: so before the mouse is even released.

Answer (score 1):

Make your canvas view respond to drags as well. Initially all its `<NSDraggingDestionation>` protocol methods would just return “no, do nothing”, but if you start a drag from within the canvas you’d keep track of that, and once the drag leaves and comes back your NSDraggingDestionation methods would return, “Ok, we accept, drag is over, don’t bother animating.”

Then you could continue tracking locally. Like, assuming your canvas had called:

```
- (void)dragImage:(NSImage *)anImage at:(NSPoint)viewLocation offset:(NSSize)initialOffset event:(NSEvent *)event pasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard source:(id)sourceObj slideBack:(BOOL)slideFlag;
```

That method would then return control to your canvas